# Android: startChildActivity (tabgroupactivity) close the app

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs

I have this code:

```
public class IntroInventario extends Activity{
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intro_inventario);
    final Database db=new Database(this);
    db.open(); 
    Cursor password=db.dammi_password();
    final EditText inserisci=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.inserisci_password);
    Button entra_inventario=(Button) findViewById(R.id.entra_inventario);
    TextView dimenticata=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.dimenticata_password);
    final Toast toast=new Toast(this);
    while(password.moveToNext()){
        if(password.getString(password.getColumnIndex("password")).equals("")){
            // primo accesso
            TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
            Intent intent = new Intent(IntroInventario.this, InventarioNoPassword.class);
            finish();
            parentActivity.startChildActivity("InventarioNoPassword",intent);
        }
    }
    db.close();
    // inserisci password
    entra_inventario.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            db.open(); 
            Cursor password_2=db.dammi_password();
            while(password_2.moveToNext()){
                if(inserisci.getText().toString().equals(password_2.getString(password_2.getColumnIndex("password")))){
                    TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), Inventario.class);
                    finish();
                    parentActivity.startChildActivity("Inventario",intent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(IntroInventario.this,"Password sbagliata",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
            db.close();
        }
    });
    // password dimenticata
    dimenticata.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), InventarioDimenticata.class);
            finish();
            parentActivity.startChildActivity("InventarioDimenticata",intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

the problem is that, if i'm in "// primo accesso", the app close itself instead of going to InventarioNoPassword.class.
It's strange because in my other projects it works.

The logcat tells:
12-07 12:43:46.756: W/InputManagerService(60): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@406705e8 (uid=10037 pid=649)

Answer (score 1):

it is better to finish your current running activity inside ***onPause()*** method. Do not use ***finish()*** method generally inside button  click . Use finish method like this . it may solve your problem

```
    @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

then in place of this

```
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), InventarioDimenticata.class);
        finish();
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("InventarioDimenticata",intent);
```

use this code it may help you

```
                Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getBaseContext(), InventarioDimenticata.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
} 

this is wrong, your activity will close for exmaple  after screen rotation

Answer (score 0):

i face similar kind of problem not sure its same but when we call finish(); before startActivity app goes in background.

so first call `parentActivity.startChildActivity("Inventario",intent);`
then `finish();`

try and give me output please.

Answer (score 0):

you are using normal intent and parent intent at the same time please use one beacuse you are using tab group activity

Comment: please check this once an match you code                            Intent previewMessage = new Intent(getParent(), AboutusActivity.class);
              TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
              parentActivity.startChildActivity("AboutusActivity", previewMessage);

Comment: check your mainfest once have you registerd this activity remove finish()

Comment: this is working for me      public void aboutus()
 {
  final Context context=this;
  btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   //@Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent previewMessage = new Intent(getParent(), AboutusActivity.class);
              TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
              parentActivity.startChildActivity("AboutusActivity", previewMessage);
            }
   
  });
 }

Comment: public void aboutus()
 {
  final Context context=this;
  btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   //@Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent previewMessage = new Intent(getParent(), AboutusActivity.class);
              TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
              parentActivity.startChildActivity("AboutusActivity", previewMessage);
            }
   
  });
 }

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your class to `TabGroupActivity`

```
  public class IntroInventario extends TabGroupActivity{
```

or else you need to create a object referencing to the TabGroupActivity class
and then use the methods in that class i.e your `startChildActivity()`

Hope this helps.